# Preventing insertion of duplicate records on concurrent hits on RESTApi Stateless Application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have spent days in finding a solution to a problem. I have a stateless spring boot application. take example of Payment (table) application using Spring boot. Following are the preventions and functionalities that I have to keep in mind while creating RESTApi.

**Preventions**

- I am not allowed to manage requests in Queue.
- Making unique keys is not an option.

**Required Functionality**

- USE RDBMS like MySQL
- App must allow simultaneous insertion. (There may be hundreds of
  users inserting at the same time)
- There must not be duplicate records (No duplicate record for same
  user)
- High Performance (Low response time)

I have tried other ways like multithreading or using synchronized method but this takes a lot time to process the request. I cannot keep user in waiting.

Basically I want to achieve a general solution for preventing concurrent requests at programming level.

Your Response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to be more specific. There must not be duplicate records: Maybe you can trace transaction id with user id for each request and avoid duplicate value.

Comment: Actually my main goal is to stopping multiple same requests by user at the same time. which will automatically stop inserting duplicate records in database.

Comment: If you have such a concern, maybe you can use optimistic lock. It is much more faster than pessimistic lock or any other locks.

Comment: You just need to use @Version anotation to cover your case. You have to check db isolation as well.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the queries in question, and whether you are using "transactions".

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Version annotation. You can use optimistic lock to avoid same row transaction commit to database.

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
   @Version
   long version;
}
```

But you have to add version column to database tables. If you can not use queue and you can not modify database tables. You have only one chance. Simply use redis or hazelcast distributed lock but it will cost you a lot.

Comment: I'm already using @Version and optimistic lock and it only helps while updating records.

Comment: So how can you override same entity? Is it even possible? If client creates a double request then you need to cancel it.

Comment: If user clicks the button twice it can be same but it means that twice purchase

Comment: take an example of signup if user tries to signup with an email but due to network issue user hits signup multiple time and user has been created multiple time with same email. i want an solution if I get concurrent request like that ignore all request except one.

Comment: user cannot click same button twice it is actually handle from frontend side but sometime due to network issue or any other issue it gets multiple clicks.